# installing w3c validator on Fedora 11

Tags: apache-http-server, php, perl, w3c-markup-validator

On Fedora 11 i have installed w3c validator using

```
yum install w3c-markup-validator
```

is this installation configure each and everything including the complete website?
followed this doc
http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html

Apache is already installed. Now how can i open validator site locally? i am trying localhost, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2 but validator website is not opening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the source](http://cvs.fedoraproject.org/viewvc/rpms/w3c-markup-validator/F-13/w3c-markup-validator-0.8.5-config.patch?revision=1.1&content-type=text%2Fplain&view=co) you want http://localhost/w3c-validator/